# Express server "failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500" after fetch request to server. How do I fix this error?

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, jwt, express-jwt

When a user enters their email and password then click login a fetch request is made to my server:

```
const RegistrationForm = (props) => {
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const handleLoginSuccess = (props) => {
return props.history.push("./homepage");
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

authApiService
  .userLogin({ email, password })
  .then((res) => {
    password.value = "";
    TokenService.saveAuthToken(res.authToken);
    handleLoginSuccess();
  })
  .catch((res) => {
    console.log(res.error);
  });
};

return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <fieldset>
    <div className="form-group">
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="registration-email">Email</label>
      </div>
      <EmailInput
        value={email}
        handleChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>

    <div className="form-group">
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="registration-password">Password</label>
      </div>
      <PasswordInput
        value={password}
        handleChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <Button type="submit" theme="registration-button">
    Log in
  </Button>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <Link to="/register-account">Create account</Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
);
};
```

Fetch request is made here:

```
userLogin({ email, password }) {
return fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/auth/login`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
 })
  .then((res) => {
    !res.ok ? res.json().then((e) => Promise.reject(e)) : res.json();
  })
  .then((res) => {
    TokenService.saveAuthToken(res.authToken);
    IdleService.registerIdleTimerResets();
    TokenService.queueCallbackBeforeExpiry(() => {
      authApiService.postRefreshToken();
    });
    return res;
  });
  },
  postRefreshToken() {
  return fetch(`${config.API_ENDPOINT}/auth/refresh`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${TokenService.getAuthToken()}`,
  },
  })
  .then((res) =>
    !res.ok ? res.json().then((e) => Promise.reject(e)) : res.json()
  )
  .then((res) => {
    TokenService.saveAuthToken(res.authToken);
    TokenService.queueCallbackBeforeExpiry(() => {
      authApiService.postRefreshToken();
    });
    return res;
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     console.log("refresh token req error");
    console.log(err);
    });
 },
```

Then on the server this is the route for this request:

```
    authRouter.post("/login", jsonBodyParser, (req, res, next) => {
   const { email, password } = req.body;
  const userLoggingIn = { email, password };

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(userLoggingIn))
    if (value == null)
     return res
    .status(400)
    .json({ error: `Missing '${key}' in request body` });
  authService
   .confirmUserNameExists(req.app.get("db"), userLoggingIn.email)
    .then((userInDb) => {
     if (!userInDb)
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ error: "Incorrect email or password" });
     });
  return authService
   .comparePasswords(userLoggingIn.password, userInDb.password)
   .then((matchedPw) => {
    if (!matchedPw)
     return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ error: "Incorrect email or password" });

  const subject = userInDb.email;
  const payload = { userId: userInDb.id };
  res.send({ authToken: authService.createJwt(subject, payload) });
   })
   .catch(next);
 });

 authRouter.post("/refresh", requiresAuthorization, (req, res) => {
  const subject = req.user.email;
  const payload = { userId: req.user.id };
  res.send({
    authToken: authService.createJwt(subject, payload),
   });
 });
```

Im getting the error in the title (500 error, failed to load resource and its pointing to the fetch request. I've tried googling and looking on stack overflow for hours and can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The goal is just to get the user logged in, redirect the user to the home page, create a JWT and store it.

Comment: Are you sure about ` .then((res) => { !res.ok ? res.json().then((e) => Promise.reject(e)) : res.json(); })` if I'm right that line returns 'undefined'.

Comment: If the response is ok then it should just return res.jon() no?

Comment: You can check it using console.log. I think this part will return 'undefined' every time because of '{' '}' and no 'return' inside.

Comment: I removed the {} but still getting the same error. I did find that the error is coming from app.js on the server from the error handler function. I looked it up in the express documentation but can’t figure out still why it’s catching that error.